# How to handle SQL injection in mssql node module

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express

In Expressjs project, I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql to connect to Microsoft SQL Server and trying to execute a stored procedure. According the to documentation of `mssql` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#sql-injection) will handle all the SQL injection what I think its not happening.

Can someone help me how to handle SQL injection in this node module?

```html
var sql = require('mssql');
var dbConfig = {};
var Connection = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
Connection.connect().then(function(_connection){
    var request = new sql.Request(_connection);
    request.verbose = true;
    request.input('username', 'patriksimek');
    request.input('password', 'delete from dbo.Users where userId =1');
    request.input('attempts', 2);
    request.execute('my_stored_procedure');
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code that generates and executes SQL commands. Are you using string concatenation or parameters?

Comment: Use prepared statements. `var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(connection)`

Comment: @Dai,, I have update the code above.

Comment: @SwarajGiri, PreparedStatement throw error for string with space. example "hello word"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a stored procedure which cannot be sql injected.

You don't need to do anything.

SQL injection is the technique to hack by pass some SQL statement to the server.

e.g., for code

```
'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ' + username
```

if I pass `username = 'xxx; DELETE FROM user;'`, then all records in users table will be gone

To protect from SQL injection

1. use query parametrization
2. use stored procedures (that you are using now)